# How to add Materialized Views in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, materialized

I want to add a Materialized Views for avg rating.

My Rate model is:

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  validates_presence_of :rate
  validates_inclusion_of :rate,in: 1..5
end
```

My Post Model is:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings
end
```

I want to find Avg for the post Using Materialized view as

```
<%= "Avg.rate:#{post.ratings.average(:rate).to_f.round(2)}"%><br>
```

I created a migration for MV as

```
class CreateAvgMatView < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW rateavg_matview AS
      SELECT AVG("ratings"."rate") FROM "ratings"
    SQL
  end
end
```

I find a issue like

```
D013:post_app naren$ rake db:migrate
== 20180813080437 CreateAvgMatView: migrating =================================
-- execute("      CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW rateavg_matview AS\n        SELECT AVG(\"ratings\".\"rate\") FROM \"ratings\"\n\n")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: near "MATERIALIZED": syntax error:       CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW rateavg_matview AS
        SELECT AVG("ratings"."rate") FROM "ratings"
```

Comment: So, what is the exact issue?

Comment: I have posted my issue

Comment: Sqlite does not support Materialized Views. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374363/how-can-a-materialized-view-be-created-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support materialized views. Please read more here [How can a materialized view be created in sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374363/how-can-a-materialized-view-be-created-in-sqlite)

You'd have to switch to different RDMS (e.g. PostgreSQL) or create a "normal" table and use [trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to update it.